# Determining when UIRefreshControl will begin refreshing before pulling started

Tags: swift, uikit, uirefreshcontrol

I'm working on subclassing UIRefreshControl in order to implement my own custom Pull-To-Refresh.

Currently, I can get the UITableViews ScrollView Offset (Y) which is allowing me to see when the user is "Pulling" and how far down they have pulled.

Because I want my Pull-To-Refresh animation to be interactive, I'm looking to have the animation progress as the pulling occurs.

**My Problem:**
I know how far down the user has pulled but in order to get the proper "precent pulled", I need to know how big the UIRefreshControl will get (Height) or what the Y of the scrollviews contentOffset will be when the UIRefreshControl begins refreshing.

If I knew the height the equation would be: CurrentHeight/Height Required for pull to begin.

Is there anyway to determine what the destined height of the Refresh Control will be when it begins refreshing?